# Different result when converting string to CRC-32

Tags: perl, crc32

I am trying to convert string to CRC-32 with perl. And i found String::CRC32. But result from that module is different with online converter. Here is my code :

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use String::CRC32;

my $resi = "nawan";
print crc32($resi) . "\n"; # --output : 3840460347
```

And output from that code is **3840460347**.

But when i try to convert "nawan" with online converter ([this online converter](http://www.timestampgenerator.com/tools/crc32-generator/)), result from that online converter is **f082b8df**.

Is there something i miss about CRC-32? Why the result is different?

Thank you.

Comment: Seems to be a different representation.

Comment: There are many 32-bit CRC definitions. You need to determine which one you need based on what protocol or format you are dealing with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result from `String::CRC32` corresponds to the decimal value of the output from the [crc32b](http://www.timestampgenerator.com/tools/crc32b-generator/) version of that website.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use String::CRC32;

my $resi = "nawan";
print sprintf("Decimal: %d, Hex: %x\n",crc32($resi), crc32($resi));
```

**output**

```
Decimal: 3840460347, Hex: e4e8c63b
```

**e4e8c63b** corresponds to the crc32b hash of 'nawan' obtained on that website.

Comment: Yeah, just found out that the result from String::CRC32 is crc32b. Do you know how to make result in crc32 with String::CRC32 ?

Comment: @nawanTSL That would involve replacing String/CRC32.pm with something that does something completely different.